# Newton's 3rd law and propellantless propulsion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, free-body-diagram

I was thinking lately about a potential misunderstanding regarding Newton's $3^\text{rd}$ law and the supposed impossibility of creating a device that moves by utilizing just internal forces (propellentless propulsion).
Below is my reasoning:

$1$. The conservation of momentum and energy is a consequence of Newton's
$3^\text{rd}$ law; however, the $3^\text{rd}$ law by itself cannot determine whether an isolated system should accelerate or not (by utilizing internal forces).
$2$. Just the conservation of momentum can determine whether a system may accelerate or not.
$3$. When the internal pair of forces (action-reaction) are rectilinear, then the outcome (there is no rigorous derivation in the literature) is, the isolated system cannot acquire momentum using internal forces.

**Question**: Assuming $(1), (2), (3)$ are true, is there a possibility of an isolated system acquiring momentum when the pair of internal forces (action-reaction) are not rectilinear?

A mathematical derivation would be very welcome.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127882/discussion-on-question-by-john-newtons-3rd-law-and-propellantless-propulsion).

Answer (score 2):

> a) The conservation of momentum and energy is a consequence of Newton's 3rd law; however, the 3rd law by itself cannot determine whether an isolated system should accelerate or not (by utilizing internal forces).

Your (a) is not correct. Mathematically, when object A interacts with object B then Newton’s 3rd law says $\vec F_{AB} = -\vec F_{BA}$ where $\vec F_{AB}$ is the force on A from B.

So, if an object is composed of $N$ particles then the net force on the object due to internal forces is: $$\Sigma_{i=1}^{N} \Sigma_{j=1}^{N} \vec F_{ij}=$$
$$\Sigma_{i=1}^{N} \Sigma_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2}\left( \vec F_{ij} + \vec F_{ji} \right) =$$
$$\Sigma_{i=1}^{N} \Sigma_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2}\left( \vec F_{ij} - \vec F_{ij} \right) =$$
$$\Sigma_{i=1}^{N} \Sigma_{j=1}^{N} \frac{1}{2}\left( 0 \right) =0$$

Since the net force due to internal forces is 0 the acceleration of the center of mass due to internal forces is also 0 by $\Sigma \vec F = m \vec a$, Newton’s 2nd law.

Comment: Hi Dale, this is all perfectly understood but what you shared above says nothing about whether the system should accelerate or not.

Comment: @John I added a concluding sentence making the connection explicit.

Comment: "Since the net force due to....". I think this is not correct because Newton's 3rd law applies not to the same object (e.g. a part of the system (one object) and the rest of the system (another object)) and you claim then the net force on the system is 0, thus no acceleration. This is exactly the point of misunderstanding I mentioned in my first post regarding determining whether an isolated system should accelerate or not using internal forces.

Comment: @John you talk as if there were a  misunderstanding  in the physics community about this issue. I am sure you actually mean that the misunderstanding is yours.

Comment: @jonny. I am speaking about the misunderstanding in the physics community attempting to justify why an isolated system should never accelerate. What Dale and the entire Literature says about this is p1=-p2 where p1 is part's momentum and p2 is the momentum of the rest of the system. Thus p1=-p2 as also Dale's derivation says nothing about whether the system should accelerate or not. This is the reason I mentioned in my first post, it is required a rigorous derivation about it where as far as I have searched, I haven't found any.  However, I could provide my own version, if the rules allow it.

Comment: @John I see, thanks for clarifying. Nobody will take you seriously on this site, you did not read a single physics book and you claim that we are wrong.

Comment: It would be different if you were asking, not lecturing

Comment: @jonny. On the contrary. What you write is correct but it cannot justify whether the isolated system should accelerate or not. In terms of action-reaction and momentum conservation isn't the following correct? "action upon a part of the system, creates a reaction force upon the rest of the system that leads to opposing momenta". Opposing momenta we have also in rocket physics although the engaging forces are considered external to the rocket system.

Comment: @jonny. I apologize if I sound like giving a lecture. My enthusiasm and determination to find an answer to this, sometimes make me overreact because to those I have made the same question, I receive the same answers (according to the literature) by overlooking what I am actually trying to point out.

Comment: @John said “I think this is not correct because Newton's 3rd law …”. It is correct, but you are right that it is not Newton’s 3rd law but Newton’s 2nd law. I have added an additional clarification.

Comment: @Dale The issue with your above derivation is that you address the problem as the net force that applies to the entire system equals to action and reaction that is not correct (again according to my understanding, I am not lecturing). If the isolated system would be able to accelerate then that would be because of the action force (as a primary cause that leads to system acceleration (reaction)). The same principle applies to rocketry.

Comment: @John the derivation is indeed correct. The net force on a system due to internal forces is zero and therefore the acceleration of the center of mass due to internal forces is zero. Full stop. It seems like you want to have a discussion rather than an answer. I recommend going to a discussion oriented site, like physicsforums.com where I am also active. This site actively discouraged discussion. We can discuss rockets there

Comment: @Dale fair enough. I will try to open a thread in the physics forum with exactly the same subject. Thanks to all for your time and having me!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a system of particles, indeed the Newton third law pairs act on different particles. For a given particle in the system the net force does not have to be zero. Internal forces in the system can accelerate the component particles and can change the total kinetic energy of the system. Hovewer, for any change in momentum produced by a force $F_{ij}$ there is an a change in opposite direction (momentum is a vector) produced by $F_{ji}$. These changes are associated with different particles, of course. As the forces are equal in magnitude and act during the same time, the magnitudes of the two changes in momentum are the same. So, when you calculate the change in momentum of the system (which is the vector sum of all momenta of the particles) you get zero from the internal forces. You don't get the same thing for the total KE because the displacement of the particles do not have to be equal (whereas the time of action of the forces is the same) and the changes don't have to have opposite signs (they may both be increases or decreases). The fact that the momentum does not change under internal forces is used to define the center of mass as a point that virtually caries the  total momentum of the system and we can say that the momentum of the COM does not change under internal forces. So, the bottom line is that the internal forces can change the KE energy of the system and can change the individual momenta of the particle. The system can expand, contract, change overall shape but the total momentum remains the same.  In most introductory textbook the study of mechanical systems that are not point-like  is restricted to rigid bodies and this may leave a distorted impression about what internal forces can and cannot do.

Comment: Hi @nasu, I think you are very close to what I have in mind. Here is the mathematical proof that a part will not change its momentum, thus the system itself, written in plain English: the action force upon a part of the system with mass $m$ creates a reaction force upon the rest of the system ($M-m$). Simultaneously (same time interval), the latter becomes the action force exerted upon another part of the system with mass $m$ located in the opposite direction, creates a reaction force upon the rest of the system ($M-m$) opposing the last action force.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray}
\vec{F}_\mathrm{A \rightarrow m}\mathrm{d}t/2 -\vec{F}_\mathrm{R \rightarrow (M-m)} \mathrm{d}t/2 - \vec{F}_\mathrm{A \rightarrow m} \mathrm{d}t/2 + \nonumber \\
\vec{F}_\mathrm{R \rightarrow (M-m)} \mathrm{d}t/2 = \vec{0}, \\
\mathrm{d}\vec{p}_\mathrm{m}/2 - \mathrm{d}\vec{p}_\mathrm{(M-m)}/2 - \mathrm{d}\vec{p}_\mathrm{m}/2 + \mathrm{d}\vec{p}_\mathrm{(M-m)}/2 = \vec{0}, \label{eq9} \\
\mathrm{d}\vec{p}_{\mathrm{m}} \cdot 0 = - \mathrm{d}\vec{p}_\mathrm{(M-m)} \cdot 0 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thus,
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{d}\vec{p}_\mathrm{m} = \vec{0} \Rightarrow \mathrm{d}\vec{p}_\mathrm{M} = \vec{0} \label{eq10}.   
\end{eqnarray}

Is the above you had also in mind?

Comment: Apparently, the proof I provided cannot be found in the literature. It tells us that any action and reaction will be self-canceled, which means there is a possibility of a situation that can prevent this. I propose such a situation exists and is by using non-rectilinear forces arising from the conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: Is what has been proposed in the following paper a viable answer to my initial question:
https://vixra.org/pdf/2107.0096v1.pdf

Please see Fig.2 and read from eq.10 and beyond.

Possible Experimental Verification (found accidentally on the internet): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ytz4DOSM2k&t=164s

Comment: The math of it was provided by Dale.  It is also in any mechanics book treating systems of particles.

Comment: The math provided by Dale as also those in the literature is correct but conceptually wrong. One cannot take the "the net force on the object due to internal forces" by considering the sum of action and reaction since they apply on a different object. Dale's derivation would be conceptually correct when there were two additional terms (as I showed above), in which it would be clearly demonstrated that $\sum \vec{F}_A = \vec{0} \Rightarrow \sum \vec{F}_R =\vec{0}$, as I showed above. Actions should be canceled themselves in order to have no reaction (results in no system acceleration).

Answer (score 1):

When you say "rectilinear," I assume you mean "collinear." I want to give a little input on this.  Newton's third law does not require the internal forces to be collinear, only equal and opposite. You can envision then a system of two particle such as this one, where both particles are at rest:
[image]

The CG is halfway between each particle. Suppose the internal forces exchanged between each particle look like this:

[image]

This situation complies with Newton's third law. There is still no net external force, as the forces cancel. A net moment, however, does arise. Therefore, Newton's third law does not preclude internal moments.

Many times though, whether tacitly or explicitly, authors will accept a "strong" form of Newton's third law, a modified version where it decrees that internal forces shall be "equal, opposite, and collinear." This is just a postulate, or a model, to make things simple. I am sure you can go digging through the literature for empirical evidence of the collinear requirement being violated. In fact, you may want to start with a google search of "Cosserat continua."

Comment: Evan, whether strong or weak the fact is that Newton's 3rd law is one meaning, the same magnitude but opposite directions. I am not searching for violations in the case of collinear forces (that would be stupid). If you read my question carefully and my comments above (see also the link to a paper and experiment), I propose the possibility of having propellantless propulsion without violating Newton's 3rd law and the conservation of momentum but using non-rectilinear (non-collinear) internal inertial forces arising from the conservation of angular momentum.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you're inside a big box, which is on a frictonless surface, with your back to one wall.  Start running towards the other wall--the box will react and travel in the opposite direction, your absolute position remains unchanged, and the other wall will come to you.  But if there is friction, and your propulsion force is lower than the static frictional maximum, you will move forward, gaining momentum.  Then when you hit the other wall, the momentum will be transferred to the box, and if it is great enough to overcome the static friction it will move the box forward.  No external propulsion.

Comment: Ed, you are addressing the case of having rectilinear internal forces (action-reaction) in an environment with surface friction. It means in outer space or in a frictionless surface, your idea will not work. My question as also what I shared with my answer above involves no surface friction as also non-rectilinear internal inertial forces. Just think for a moment about why the birds acquire momentum (I am speaking not about aerodynamics and hovering). The same misunderstanding applies to propellers.

Answer (score 0):

Directed her from elsewhere (Quora)  sounds like the old Dean Drive revisited. This was a classical science fair demo where rotating masses were converted to a linear thrust.

I submit the following.
.. .. ..
I have a big problem right out of the box.

I would ask: How can the action-reaction pair be non-rectilinear / colinear? they are inseparable.

I maintain that they are not really two separate and distinct forces as the old N3 wording suggests, but that it is better to look at as a force always having the two parts acting in opposite directions.

It is like you can not compress (or stretch) a spring from only one end. It takes external forces on both ends.

Then, from the spring’s point of view, it is only doing ONE thing to exert these two parts and that is returning to its original length. That is one force of either extension or retraction.
.. ..
Consider:
We are on frictionless skate boards.
Place a spring between my hand and your shoulder.  I push you.
My constricting extensor muscle changes the geometry of my arm joints to put a force on you and one on me, thus pushing us apart.
That spring supplies those two parts by extending to its original length, therefore pushing us both apart.
..
From the view if my arm muscle, or the spring, only one bidirectional force is applied, NOT TWO!
My muscle only contracts and the spring only extends.

I suggest to readers that Newton’s original wording has given us an incorrect view of the nature of forces. It isn’t a pair of things, but a dual acting thing and, therefore it cannot be broken apart into two non anti-colinear forces..
Regards

P.S. Watching that video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ytz4DOSM2k&t=164s
Is is clear it requires friction.  Hang it from a string and if it really works, it will hang non-vertical, to one side.

Comment: Brilliant question! Think for a moment what is the difference between a contact and a non-contact force or between a contact and an inertial force. 
Besides the apparent, a non-contact e.g. acting through a field has the ability to be induced. An inertial force is in essence an object’s changing momentum.
Consequently, in order to achieve a non-rectilinear internal interaction between a part of the system and the rest of the system, one has to engage in changing angular momenta (in a way they have the ability to be induced through the conservation of angular momentum).

Comment: This is the reason I mention in the introduction of the paper “accelerating an isolated system using non-rectilinear internal inertial forces arising from the conservation of angular momentum.”. Using contact rectilinear forces we arrive at the conclusions you mentioned above.

Comment: Birds, airplanes, and ships acquire momentum by pushing the medium using non-rectilinear inertial forces, otherwise, they would be able just to hover (aerodynamics) or float (hydrodynamics). Of course, the literature ignores this crucial detail and speaks generally “because of the action-reaction principle” which says nothing about the underlying mechanism. Neither Newton’s 3rd law nor the conservation of momentum is wrong, just our understanding (blame the literature about it).

Comment: Contrary to what one might expect, hanging that car (YouTube video) from a string and powering it, will result in acquiring horizontal changing momentum (acceleration). It doesn't require fiction to work. If one adds friction to the process then the car would normally accelerate in the opposite direction through an additional action-reaction pair coming now from the interaction of the wheels and the table. This is something that does not happen in that video.

Comment: For the HALF cycle where m&m are above the X axis [figure below] it produces a movement of "M" in the positive X direction and for the half-cycle below the X axis, the motion of "M" is in the negative X direction.  On average over a cycle there is no net movement.  This is the Dean drive.  Google it.

Comment: You just confirmed that my idea should work for the half-cycle in one direction and then on the other half-cycle, M will go in the opposite direction. Of course over a complete cycle, there is no net movement. Preventing acceleration below X-Axis is a technical and not a physics challenge. The main argument of those claiming will not work is that internal forces will not allow the system to move in either direction. If the Dean Drive (I never studied it) does the same then it works in principle (within a half-cycle).

Comment: Small correction: A half-cycle on the above figure is equivalent to 180° arc (and not what Steve just claimed) covered by each eccentric mass where the acceleration of M has still the same direction (opposing that of the eccentric masses).

Comment: John,
A half cycle _IS_ 180°. You say the same thig as I.
.
a) IF you continue through the next 180° for a full 360°, the opposite happens and all the masses return to the start with NO net Displacement. 
.
b) IF you reverse the rotation and repeatedly traverse the first 180° back-and-forth, you *MUST* then consider the forces required to accelerate the masses to a stop and reverse their direction.  You will find that those forces reverse the effects of the 180° rotation.  NO net gain in displacement.
.
That _IS_ the Dean Drive and it produces NO thrust for the system. 
- - Regards

Comment: Hi Steve! I cannot clearly understand what you mean with (b), however (a) alone proves the propellantless propulsion in principle, again without assuming table friction as a necessary ingredient for this to work. I am still waiting for your response (Quora) about your objection regarding the rotating unbalance "isn’t going to rise up".

Comment: I've addressed it all.  You have no continuous, single direction (unidirectional) force on "M" because its motion only lasts for ONE HALF of the rotation and is COMPLETELY REVERSED the very next half cycle. .. .. .. (v) was my guess about what you propose to do after that half cycle. Do you reverse the rotation so the small masses "m" go back and only swing around the one side??

Comment: Can't edit (v) is supposed to be (b)...

Comment: I put an answer on Quora that clearly and more exactly addressed the motions of "M". During the 180 degrees of rotation above the dotted line, "M" moves down then up, thus returning to the start elevation. The reveres happens on the next 180 degrees. .. .. .."M" has NO net displacement.  Therefore, there is no "propulsion".

Comment: Hi Steve. I address all these issues in Quora (just posted). StackExchange is good for one seeking some answers but it is not suitable for discussing things thoroughly, unfortunately. Thank you very much for your critical comments and helpful suggestions. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I tried to be very specific on Aug 15th on Quora.  Have you progressed on any of this?